# wireshark with ssl

Tags: ssl, wireshark

JKJS

Even if a packet has version 0x0301 ( TLS v1 ) , wireshark is showing SSL instead of TLSv1 in protocol column.

I,myself have constructed an TLS handshake packet.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

It's because it's roughly the same thing. SSLv3 and TLS 1.x are virtually the same protocol with different version numbers. The version number for SSLv3 is `{ 3, 0 }`, and it's `{ 3, 1 }` for TLS 1.0.

(SSLv2 would have much more different packets.)

Comment: Problem is that wireshark itself sometimes shows SSL for TLS type client hello and somtimes shows TLSv1 for TLS type client hello.Why this random behaviour does exist?